# rewrite main domain to a sub-directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mybb

I already tried many different "solutions" from here, but none of them work.

I have a domain, which I want to re-write to inside mybb directory.

So:
`http://www.example.com` or
`http://example.com`

to

```
http://www.example.com/mybb
```

But obviously, I want this to be transparent so that the `mybb` won't show up in the address.

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?forumdobengal\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mybb
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /example/$1 [L]
```

But this just shows the root folder.

I ended up using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.forumdobengal.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mybb/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mybb/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forumdobengal.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mybb/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mybb/$1
```

This worked. But something on the `.htaccess` inside `/mybb` is giving a redirect loop.

This is the content of the `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://www.forumdobengal.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=yearview&calendar=$1&year=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ http://www.forumdobengal.com/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Forum-([^./]+)$ forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Topico-([^./]+)$ showthread.php?google_seo_thread=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Anuncio-([^./]+)$ announcements.php?google_seo_announcement=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Usuario-([^./]+)$ member.php?action=profile&google_seo_user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Calendario-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?google_seo_calendar=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Evento-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?action=event&google_seo_event=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

#Redirect 301 /mybb/ http://www.forumdobengal.com
    
    RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)$ tags.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^ask/([^/]+)$ tags.php?sear=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/([^-/]+)$ tags.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^tagsitemap.xml$ tags.php?sitemap=1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^tagsitemap-page-([^/]+).xml$ tags.php?sitemap=1&spage=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^deletetags=([^/]+)$ tags.php?deltags=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^delspectag=([^/]+)&delspectagtid=([^/]+)$ tags.php?delspectag=$1&delspectagtid=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^tag/$ tags.php [L,QSA]

    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

what about this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?forumdobengal\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mybb
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /mybb/$1 [L]
```

I think you are mixing directories path and URL. You take a look at [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that by such role your content will be available by different URLs which is an obvious duplicate content issue! It is recommended to use just one URL per document else you need a canonical specification. If SEO is not a factor and if your sub-domain is a directory in /public_html/ then you can put this code in your /public_html/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L]
```